# Передача пропса в динамический компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет.
Возник вопрос.
Как можно передать пропс в динамический компонент ?

У меня компоненты вставляются через

```
<component :is="valueSelect"></component>
```

Либо как можно переделать код, чтобы динамически подставлять компоненты внутрь другого компонента

Answer (score 1):

Для динамической передачи реквизитов вы можете добавить `v-bind` директиву в свой динамический компонент и передать объект, содержащий имена и значения ваших реквизитов.

> Если вы хотите передать все свойства объекта в качестве реквизита, вы
> можете использовать `v-bind` без аргумента ( `v-bind` вместо `:prop-name`).
> Например, для данного `post` объекта:
>
> ```
> export default {
>   data() {
>     return {
>       post: {
>         id: 1,
>         title: 'My Journey with Vue'
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Следующий шаблон:
> `<BlogPost v-bind="post" />`

[Связывание нескольких свойств с использованием объекта](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)

и рабочий пример:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  template: `
    <component is="FirstComponent" v-bind="{ prop1: 'prop1', counter, }"/>
    <component is="SecondComponent" v-bind="{ prop2: 'prop2', counter }" v-on="{onTestClick}" />
   `,
  setup() {

    const counter = Vue.ref(0);
    const onTestClick = () => {
      counter.value += 1
    }

    return {
      counter,
      onTestClick,
    }
  },
})

const FirstComponent = {
  props: ['prop1', 'counter'],
  template: `
  <figure>
    <figcaption>FirstComponent</figcaption>
    <code>
      {{$props}}
    </code>
  </figure>
  `
}
app.component('FirstComponent', FirstComponent)

const SecondComponent = {
  props: ['prop2', 'counter'],
  emits: ['onTestClick'],
  template: `
  <figure>
    <figcaption>SecondComponent 
      <button @click="$emit('onTestClick')">counter ++</button></figcaption>
    <code>
      {{$props}}
    </code>
  </figure>
  `
}
app.component('SecondComponent', SecondComponent)

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```